# Como enviar um arquivo de áudio do celular Android para o computador?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou trabalhando num aplicativo em Android que faz  gravação da chamada telefônica num aparelho de celular.

Só que preciso enviar uma cópia do arquivo de áudio para o computador via TCP/IP.
Já tenho uma função que envia texto para o computador. Mas como enviar um arquivo de áudio ?

No computador já tenho um servidor feito em Delphi que se comunica com o celular e vice versa. Também sei como fazer, em Delphi, para receber o arquivo no computador. Só não sei fazer o código para enviar a partir do celular.

Alguém tem uma ideia?

Comment: Espero que ajude em algo este link [sending-file-over-tcp-between-android-and-pc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508811/sending-file-over-tcp-between-android-and-pc)

Comment: Olá. Sim, é exatamente isto que procurava. Me pareceu bem simples, basta enviar bit-a-bit. Vou testar agora. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

> De forma assíncrona ....

```
    Socket socket  = null;
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;

    try {
        socket = new Socket("192.168.198.1", 8901);
        bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        int counter = 0;
        String path = "/mnt/sdcard/ad.wav";
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
        byte jj[] = new byte[1024];
        while ((counter = bufferedInputStream.read(jj, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            fileOutputStream.write(jj, 0, counter);
        }
        fileOutputStream.close();            
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }
```

[fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508811/sending-file-over-tcp-between-android-and-pc)

Apenas organizei o código sugerido nos comentários pelo **checkmate**.